# Get names and types of a Python module's attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys


def attrs_and_types(mod_name):

    print('Attributes and their types for module {}:'.format(mod_name))
    print()

    for num , attr in enumerate(dir(eval(mod_name))):

        print("{idx}: {nam:30}  {typ}".format(
        idx=str(num + 1).rjust(4),
        nam=(mod_name + '.' + attr).ljust(30), 
        typ=type(eval(mod_name + '.' + attr))))

attrs_and_types(sys.__name__)
```

Can anyone help me with these two lines?

```
for num, attr in enumerate(dir(eval(mod_name))):
    attrs_and_types(sys.__name__)
```

I don't understand why `sys.__name__` is passed as an argument to the function. It's supposed to be the name of the module. Why is `.__name__` added to `sys`?

And in the `for` loop `num, attr` is checking in this:

```
enumerate(dir(eval(mod_name)))
```

What is this? Is it a memory location?

Comment: As you say, it's supposed to be the name of the module. `module.__name__` **is** the name of `module`; `sys.__name__ == 'sys'`. And no, that's not *"a memory location"* - I suggest you head to the Python docs and look up what `eval`, `dir` and `enumerate` do, or simply add in some `print` function calls to find out what each step does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is `.__name__` added to sys?

Every module has a `__name__` attribute attached to it that has its name. It's just how things are.

> What is this? Is it a memory location?

Nope, the author decided to use `eval` (for some reason) to evaluate the string passed (`sys.__name__`) and get back the module object. I cannot see why he decided to do so, it is quite dangerous to allow the function to receive an arg which you then pass to `eval`, so don't do this.

A better implementation for this (without using the `inspect` module) would look like this:

```
import sys

def attrs_and_types(mod):
    name = mod.__name__
    print('Attributes and their types for module {}:\n'.format(name))
    fmt = "{idx}: {nam:30}  {typ}"
    for num , attr in enumerate(dir(sys)):
        s = fmt.format(
            idx=str(num + 1).rjust(4),
            nam=(name + '.' + attr).ljust(30), 
            typ=type(attr)
        )
        print(s)

attrs_and_types(sys)
```

`eval` isn't required if you just pass the module object directly. Even if you did pass the `__name__` though, you'd still be able to get back the module via `sys.modules` in a safer manner.